# Firestore data into a Model class

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, model, getter-setter

**I have the following Firestore Database;**

[image]

In my first page I query all the '**Other**' collection documents and list the fields '*name*' & '*surname*' of each document with a **button** that will redirect me to *that person's* page.

```
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Other')
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.hasData) {
          var documents = snapshot.data!.docs;

          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return TextButton(
                child: Text(documents[index]['name']),
                onPressed: () => Get.to(() => const Person()),
              );
            },
          );
        } 
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I know that I could simply add final parameters of '*name*' and '*surname*' into **Person** class like this;

```
class Person extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String surname;

  const Person({Key? key, required this.name, required this.surname}) : super(key: key);
```

But in the **Person** class I will have to pass that information to following pages and passing parameters through constructors back to back doesn't seem like a good practice.

From my knowledge with other programming languages I could simply generate a **Model class** with *Setters* and *Getters* and once a button of a person is clicked I'd set all of his information in this model class and get them in the following pages and so on.

Would be a good practice generating a model class for this purpose in Flutter/Dart? If so, how can I generate this model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use this temporary solution due lack of answers and pass this model class to every widget where the information is required. My search for the best-practice on this is still going on but this also does the work.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class PersonModel {
  String name, surname;

  PersonModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.surname,
  });

  factory PersonModel.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return PersonModel(
      name: map['name'],
      surname: map['surname'],
    );
  }

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'surname': surname,
    };
  }
}
```